# How to prevent checking checkbox when added dynamically to a div?

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

so I've been struggling with this issue.

I want to add a checkbox into a div dynamically by clicking a button. Let's say I already have 2 checkboxes in the div, then I uncheck those 2. When I click the button, the checkboxes become 3 (which is what I want), but all those 3 will be checked. What I want is when I add a checkbox, the other checkbox(s)' checked state remain the same as before.

Here is my code (http://jsfiddle.net/gr2o47wt/4/):

HTML:

```
<div id="chkbox_container">
    <input type="checkbox" checked>Check<br />
</div>
<input type="button" value="Add CheckBox" onClick="addCheckBox();">
```

JavaScript:

```
function addCheckBox() {
    txt = "<input type=\"checkbox\" checked>Check<br />";
    document.getElementById('chkbox_container').innerHTML += txt;
}
```

Thanks in advance for your answers! :)

Comment: In addition to David Thomas's answer (which you should accept because it's right!) there is no `</input>`.  http://validator.w3.org/ is your friend.  Edit: I note that `</input>` is now gone from the code.  Good.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `insertAdjacentHTML()` rather than manipulating the `innerHTML`:

```
<input type="button" value="Add CheckBox" 
onClick="document.getElementById('chkbox_container').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend','<input type=\'checkbox\' checked=\'checked\' />Check<br />');">
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/gr2o47wt/10/).

The problem you had was that the original HTML (as returned by `innerHTML`) is from the *source* of the page, not the DOM; and therefore the checked/unchecked nature of the checkbox originally in place was restored.

`insertAdjacentHTML()` simply adds the HTML string in the specified place (`'beforeend'` in this case).

More or less as an aside, it's worth trying, where possible, to keep your event-handling outside of your HTML elements; and binding those event-handlers in the JavaScript itself. This makes for somewhat easier maintainability, and would lead to code like the following:

```
// note that I gave the button an 'id' for simplicity:
var button = document.getElementById('addCheckboxes');

button.addEventListener('click', function () {
    document.getElementById('chkbox_container').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<input type=\'checkbox\' checked=\'checked\' />Check<br />');
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/gr2o47wt/9/).

Finally, some of your HTML is invalid (or at least erroneous), an `<input />` is a void element, it can have *no* descendants; therefore it either has no closing tag (just: `<input>`) or self-closes (`<input />`).

Further, the text beside the checkboxes is a little misleading, usually with an HTML form the text beside the `<input />` will focus that input; that's achieved by using a `<label>` element to associate the text with the control, for example:

```
<label><input type="checkbox" /> click</label>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/gr2o47wt/12/).

Or:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="inputElementID" />
<label for="inputElementID">click</label>
```

But this latter form does require the dynamic generation of `id`s (which is a little beyond the scope of this question).

References:

- [`insertAdjacentHTML()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.insertAdjacentHTML).

Comment: add this HTML `'<input type=\'checkbox\' checked/>Check<br />'` add checked property also, it will complete OP's requirment.

Comment: Thanks @DavidThomas, it works like a charm! I didn't realize that the innerHTML will restore the checked/unchecked nature.

Comment: It doesn't restore the checked/unchecked state, it *restores*/*replaces* the HTML. @Mritunjay: thanks! I'd stripped things out to debug the fault(s) and forgot to put them back... >.<

Comment: Thanks @DavidThomas for the event-handling tips, I'll keep that in mind. :D